# Horrible MySQL database performance after upgrading from 5.5 to 5.6

Tags: mysql, amazon-rds, upgrade

I have run into a performance problem that I don't know how to solve with MySQL after Amazon forced us to upgrade our 5.5 MySQL instance to 5.6.

We have a stored procedure which executed in about 10 seconds on version 5.5, but on version 5.6 it takes 5 minutes to complete.  I have narrowed the problem down to some very basic and simple SQL which is executing inside of a loop.  It seems that dropping and re-creating a temporary table in memory takes MUCH longer now and so does simple insert statements.  Here is the basic flow of the procedure:

```
loop
  drop temporary table if exists
  create temporary table (engine = memory)
  insert into temporary table values (...)...
  insert into temporary table values (...)...
  insert into temporary table values (...)...
  insert into temporary table values (...)...
end loop
```

The insert statements are very simple - there is no subquery involved.  It's just a simple insert statement.  If I comment out the insert statements and only execute the drop / create statements and nothing else, performance is still horrible (although improved).  I tried creating a regular table and removing the drop / create and executing only the insert statements, and again it was still horrible performance (but improved).

Because the statements executing are so incredibly simple, I don't think it's possible to fix this issue without a significant rewrite of the application (so no looping occurs).

I am hopeful that someone can point me to a configuration setting that I can change which will improve performance.  In my research, I have already found recommendations to modify various settings that have not helped.  The settings I have already checked are:

- innodb_stats_persistent
- innodb_file_per_table
- innodb_buffer_pool_size

Comment: It's probably worth checking that the upgrade didn't reset config values like `max_heap_table_size` and `tmp_table_size` to the MySQL defaults.

Comment: You should compare MySQL rds parameter group contents before and after the upgrade. Focus on non default values, especially performance related ones such as `tmp_table_size`. When upgrading, you probably reverted to a new `default.mysql5.6` parameter group and all your optimizations were gone. You can use RDS console to compare previous and current parameter group.

Comment: @Cascader - I have done the comparison as you suggested, and I can't find any relevant diferences.  You are correct that when I upgraded the database it defaulted to the `default.mysql5.6` group.  I created a new group and made sure the parameters matched wherever I could.  The problem persists.

Comment: Any chance your IO burst balance is depleted due to the upgrade?

Comment: @Cascader - I'm not sure how to answer that (I'm not a DBA, but I'm trying my best).  The database was a `db.m3.medium` when it was upgraded.  I changed it to a `db.m3.2xlarge` and that made no difference.  Does that answer your question?

Comment: Instance class will improve CPU and memory but not IO (disk). You can check your RDS console, Monitoring tab: look for "Burst Balance" graph (should be the last one on last page).

Comment: Burst Balance is steady at 100%.  Is that good or bad?

Comment: Good. We ruled out IO bottleneck.

Comment: We may need to see the tables and the query.

Comment: How much RAM do you have?  What is the setting of `max_heap_table_size`?

Comment: @RickJames - This is an RDS instance (db.m3.medium) with 3.75 GB RAM.  The `max_heap_table_size` is set to `21474304`.